# If $G$ is a group and $|G|=6$ show that there exists a $a \in G$ such that $O(a)=6$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

$O(a)=|\langle a\rangle|$, my professor states that $a \in (G-\{e\})$ so the Lagrange theorem implies to $O(a)>1$ and $O(a)|6$, I'd like to understand just this part of the proof which I was given to so far. Note that there is no intersections containing $a$ between the subgroups of $G$ so how would $O(a)>1$? What would make me sure that there exists at least one $a$ such that $O(a)>1$?

Comment: This is all very hard to follow.  Surely you know that the claim in the header is false (just think about $S_3$).  But then the body of your post appears to asking something altogether different.  Though, again, you surely know that only the identity has order $1$.   Please edit your post for clarity.

Answer (score 6):

What you want to prove is clearly fasle.

Consider, $G=S_3$ and you can't find any element of order $6$.

To ensure the existence of an element of order $6$ , you need  the group to be Ablelian.

**In an abelian group of order $6$ , there exists an element of order $6$.**

You can you Cauchy's theorem for finite abelian group or Sylow's theorem.

Note: There are two groups of order $6$ upto Isomorphism.

$|G|=6\implies G\cong S_3 $ or $\Bbb{Z_6}$

Comment: "**In an abelian group of order $6$ , there exists an element of order $6$.**". Well, true, but only because an abelian group of order $6$ is also cyclic. By itself, in general abelianiness doesn't suffice for a group to be cyclic.

Comment: Please note that "abelian group of order $6$ ". Order of  the group play a vital role along with commutative property. The statment doesn't encourage to consider any abelian group to be cyclic.